# how to obtain the information about System Configuration in RCP 4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rcp, e4

I am trying to obtain information about the system configuration in RCP 4 application. I got a link [RCP3 System Configuration](https://github.com/vogella/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/ConfigurationInfo.java) which implemented in RCP3 for getting the system configuration. WorkbenchMessages properties and WorkbenchPlugin are used to get the system configuration in RCP3 application but in RCP4 those are not available. How can I implement to get the system configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The `ConfigurationInfo` class you reference is using the `org.eclipse.ui.systemSummarySection` extension point and calling the `ISystemSummarySection` interfaces it defines to get the system summary.

This extension point and the `ISystemSummarySection` interface do not exist in a plain e4 app so this information is not available using this code.

You may be able to get some of the information by looking at the individual classes that implement `ISystemSummarySection` and copying the code for  those parts that don't use 3.x compatibility mode classes.

For example the `ConfigurationLogDefaultSection` class just uses `System.getProperties()` to list the system properties section.